# How to reduce consumption on arduino system?

Tags: arduino

This is a simple example.
How to reduce total power consumption without modify any hardware,
and only modify the program???
Of course `delay(1000)` shouldn't be changed.

Thank you everyone.

PS.
Because after I see this video

http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTMxNDc0NDAxNg==.html?f=26075379&from=y1.7-3&utm_campaign=Newsletter-CN-Sep2015-Taiwan%28v1%29&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua,

and then I want applicate on my project. But I still don't know how to use ""picopower""to reduce my arduino system.

```
// Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards.  
// give it a name:
int led = 13;

void setup() {                
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}

void loop() {  
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   
    delay(1000);               
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);    
    delay(1000);               
}
```

Comment: you can shutdown lot of unused stuff see http://heliosoph.mit-links.info/arduino-powered-by-capacitor-first-tests/ you can blink very fast your led, human eye won't see the blink.

Comment: @Ôrel 's idea is not bad.. You can just use the function `analogWrite` instead of `digitalWrite` (of course on a PWM-enabled pin) and find the lowest acceptable value to reduce the LED consumption. Moreover usually on other uC you can use the low power mode: I'm not sure if there is one on the Atmega 328P, but if there is you can sleep the program until a timer fires an interrupt, and then set it so that it resumes the main loop. Anyway... Tell us what you want to do and probably You'll receive better answers

Comment: Thank you,everyone. Because after I see this video,http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTMxNDc0NDAxNg==.html?f=26075379&from=y1.7-3&utm_campaign=Newsletter-CN-Sep2015-Taiwan%28v1%29&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua                and then I want applicate on my project. But I still don't know how to use ""picopower""to reduce my arduino system.

Comment: you can replace the arduino with a ne555

Comment: This excellent article describes several power saving techniques: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11497